# Unserialize error in Drupal Commons 3 for unathenticated pages

Tags: 7

I've having the darnedest time finding a solution to the following error that is seen on my login screen to [Drupal Commons 3](http://drupal.org/project/commons) running on Drupal 7.22.

**Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 52 of 77 bytes in registration_entity_settings() (line 863 of /var/www/html/profiles/commons/modules/contrib/registration/registration.module).**

We are additionally using [FBOauth](http://drupal.org/project/fboauth). Outside of that this is a new install.

To try to disect the issue a bit more I added the following right above the `unserialize` call.

```
 859     if ($result) {
 860         print '<pre>';
 861         print_r($result);
 862         print '</pre>';
 863         $result['settings'] = unserialize($result['settings']);
 864     }
 865   }
```

This dumps what is in $result['settings']. I thought perhaps a value was incorrectly serialized in the first place, but I cannot see what the issue might be. The output dump...

```
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 5
    [entity_type] => node
    [capacity] => 0
    [status] => 1
    [send_reminder] => 0
    [reminder_date] => 
    [reminder_template] => 
    [open] => 
    [close] => 
    [settings] => a:2:{s:12:"from_address";s:17:"admin@example.com";s:22:"multiple_slots";i:0;}
)
```

This error disappears once I'm logged in. This is a sandbox/development box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this was a development server, I just blew away the current install and database. This hasn't occurred since a reinstall of Commons 3.